# Run .exe File with Dependencies on Location

Tags: c++, visual-studio, command-line

I have a Visual Studio project (Project 1) that generates an executable file (a.exe). I have a project (Project 2) that runs the executable from project (Project 1) multiple times with different command line arguments. On the command line I can run:

```
C:\filepath\Solution\Project1> a.exe                 //command 1
```

But I cannot run:

```
C:\filepath\Solution\Project2> C:\filepath\Solution\Project1\a.exe    //command 2
```

Because the .exe file depends on the surrounding file hierarchy.

In Project 2, I can run a system call to execute command 2, but I hit hierarchy/location dependency issues. The Solution structure is as follows:

```
Solution
--> Project 1
    --> a.exe
--> Project 2
    --> main.cpp    // this will run system call to command 2
```

Is there any way I can get around this without changing the a.exe file?

Comment: Where are the dependencies actually located? It sounds like they are in the `Project1` folder. If so, then both cases you describe should work, since the folder that `a.exe` is physically located in in the first place the OS looks for dependencies, regardless of the CWD used when launching `a.exe`.  Unless `a.exe` is coded to *explicitly* load dependencies at runtime relative to the CWD, in which case you are SOL without altering `a.exe``'s code to stop relying on the CWD. Otherwise, the dependencies need to be placed somewhere on the OS's search path.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Perhaps I should rephrase. a.exe will only run in the Project1 directory as it uses both input file data and class files from the surrounding Project1 file hierarchy. I do not know if this is specific to Visual Studio executables or simply how the project has been developed.

Comment: That is not specific to Visual Studio.  Chances are, `a.exe` is simply coded to load dependent files using paths that are relative to the CWD.  That is bad practice and should be rewritten.  If the files are relative to wherever `a.exe` is located, then `a.exe` should be recoded to query its own path at runtime and then form absolute paths based on that to load the depend files with. Otherwise, `a.exe` should be recoded to have an option to specify where the dependent files are located.

Answer (score 0):

In Project2, how are you executing Project1's .exe? If you set the Current Working Directory (CWD) to the folder where Project1's .exe resides, it should work as expected:

```
var p = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Project1\bin\project1.exe");
p.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Project1\bin";
Process.Start(p);
```

If this doesn't work for whatever reason, you can simply copy the entirety of Project1's binary output and the associated file structure into Project2's output folder. There are two ways to do this:

Option 1 (preferred): Add the binary output of Project1 to Project2. To do this, right-click on the Project2 node in Solution Explorer, select Add | Existing item... In the "Add Existing Item" dialog, change the file type to "All Files". Navigate to Project1's bin folder, select the Project1 .exe and all dependencies, click the "down arrow" on the right side of the "Add" button, and select "Add as link". In Solution Explorer, select the newly-added file links in Project2, and in Properties change "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer". For each subfolder in Project1's bin folder, you must use Solution Explorer to create a new corresponding folder in Project1, then repeat this process for all files in that subfolder.

Option 2: Create a post-build step to copy Project1's binaries and surrounding folder heirarchy to Project2's bin folder. To do this, right-click on the Project2 node in Solution Explorer and select Properties. Go to Build Events, and enter a Post-build command line such as the following:

```
xcopy "C:\Project1\bin\" "$(TargetDir)" /S
```

Option 1 is preferred because with Option 2, external tools are less likely to realize Project 2's dependency on Project1. In both cases, Project2 must be updated to run the Project1 .exe directly from Project2's output folder.

Good luck!